# Biztalk wcf-sql not able to configure

Tags: adapter, biztalk, biztalk-2010, lob

I am running into a weird problem with the installation / configuration of the BizTalk 2010 Adapter Pack.  I am running BizTalk 2010 cluster on Windows Server 2008 R2, wanted to get WCF-SQL to work so I installed the 64 bit of LOB, 64-bit BizTalk Adapter Pack, 32-bit BizTalk Adapter Pack.

I was able to see the WCF-SQL adapter in the list of adapters, and created a new handler for it.  Everything seemed to be working fine.  However when I created a receive location that uses the WCF-SQL type, and click on Configure, I got this error:

> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.  (mscorblib)
>
> Additional information: Binding not found: sqlBinding
>   (Microsoft.Adapters.Common.Biztalk).

I double checked the machine.config for both framework and framework64, .net framework 2.0 and 4.0, they all have "sqlbindings" entries.

By the way, I had it working on one of my development box, but when I tried to set up my server and that's when I run into this problem.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Install in the following order:

1. 64-bit WCF LOB Adapter SDK SP2
2. 64-bit BizTalk Adapter Pack
3. 32-bit BizTalk Adapter Pack

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that I have been doing things not correctly.  Instead of manually installing those components, go to BizTalk setup, one of the menu item is to install the adapter pack. Just follow the instruction there, and everything worked out for me.

Comment: Can you please mark this as the answer to your question, so it will help others? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason of this weird behaviour is maybe you have installed the wrong version of BizTalk Adapter Pack.

For BizTalk 2010, you have to install the 2010 version of the Adapter Pack, which can be found on BizTalk 2010 DVD/image.

You also have to pay attention to WCF LOB Adapter SDK version: you need the 2010 version which can be also found on the DVD/image.

The former versions of WCF LOB Adapter SDK and BizTalk Adapter Pack can be installed (nothing will stop you on that), but only works with BizTalk 2009.

Answer (score 0):

Not being facetious, but have you restarted your Host Instance?

Adding a handler requires a Host Instance restart.